# How to pass data to other controllers and views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I get the user's userID from Login Controller and pass it to the other controllers and views?

LOGIN CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index(Table_User user)
        {
            var user1 = repo.Find(x => x.UserMail== user.UserMail);
     
            if (user1 != null)
            {
                if (SecurityAlgorithms.CheckMD5Hash(user.UserPassword, user1.UserPassword))
                {
                    
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user1.UserName, false);
                    Session["user1"] = user.UserName;

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
                }
                
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Check your password!";
                    return View("Index", user);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you try TempData? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/passing-data-from-one-controller-to-another-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: @donstack `TempData` is only used to pass unstructured data to the controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tempdata or use  **return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { userID= user.userID });**